# Saving Both Id and name in mysql database (php)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to solve a problem with a drop-down list in PHP.

I have a drop-down list which only saves the "**id**" in the database of the selected data. I need to know if it is possible to also save the "**name**" of the selected data?

**For example:**

I select x category from the drop-down list which saves the id in the column "**category_id**" in the database. I have a column called "**category_name**" where I want to save also the "**name**" of the selected category in the dropdown list.

Anyone help on how to do it?

This is the code I made so far:

```
                <div class="form-group all">
                    <?= lang("category", "category") ?>
                    <?php
                    $cat[''] = "";
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $cat[$category->id] = $category->name;
                    }
                    echo form_dropdown('category', $cat, (isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : ($product ? $product->category_id : '')), 'class="form-control select" id="category" placeholder="' . lang("select") . " " . lang("category") . '" required="required" style="width:100%"')
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Is not a good idea to save category_name on a table that is not categories, because it could change at any time and you must update the new name on all tables/records. Why do you need the category name to be saved?

Comment: For analytics purpose I need not only id but also the names. That’s why is important for us. We will access the database also from 3d part api. Any help or suggestion will be great.

Comment: I still can't understand why do you need category name, but can't help if you don't show the code you're using to save data.